# LINQ to SQl, Self Referencing an Extended Class

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a "Literal" class that defines a text value and an ID. I want to build a static method that is simply "FromValue(string)" within the Literal class (LINQ to SQL), so that it'll return the proper Literal instance from a given value.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do this, though. I mean, I can call it in code everytime I need it, but it would be much more convenient and time saving to just wrap it into the class itself.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Context
{
    public partial class Literal
    {
        public static Literal FromValue(string value)
        {
            // linq code, how do I reference the existing data context?
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "existing data context"? There may well be more than one data context alive at the point of the call to `FromValue`, e.g.:

```
using (FooDataContext ctx1 = new FooDataContext())
using (FooDataContext ctx2 = new FooDataContext())
{
    Literal.FromValue(...); // which one?
}
```

You'll have to pass it as parameter, there really isn't any better way.

Also note that you won't be able to use `FromLiteral` in your LINQ2SQL queries (since the query parser and translator has no idea what it does).

Comment: If he needs to use FromLiteral() from linq2sql queries, he could have it return an IQueryable.  I agree thought he best thing is to just take the DataContext as an input parameter.

Comment: Mostly trying to make it more simple for assignment, rather than actual query. I can query by the name easily enough. Just trying to avoid making a new object, running a query, and then assigning it everytime the literal needs to be assigned to something.

Comment: What I means is using `FromLiteral()` in a `select`. It won't work no matter what.

Comment: No, this isn't intended to be used during a select.

Answer (score 0):

Right, well, the "FromLiteral" is what I'm using to assign it to a Key that it is attached to. Like this...

```
unit.Ring.Keys.Add(new Key(Literal.FromValue("Name",database), item[0]));
```

Where 'database' is the instance of the datacontext. I just wanted to see if there was a better way to do it. I want to assign them by string value, you see, I don't know the ID as is proper.